# Docker healthcheck command not found inside container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-image, docker-build

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM mongo

COPY docker-healthcheck /usr/local/bin/

HEALTHCHECK CMD ["docker-healthcheck"]
```

docker-healthcheck looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

host="$(hostname --ip-address || echo '127.0.0.1')"

if mongo --quiet "$host/test" --eval 'quit(db.runCommand({ ping: 1 }).ok ? 0 : 2)'; then
    exit 0
fi

exit 1
```

Although this is exactly the same as [this example](https://github.com/docker-library/healthcheck/tree/master/mongo) the healthcheck returns the following error:
`"Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"docker-healthcheck\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions were wrong on the `docker-healthcheck` file. They were `644` but should be `755` for Docker to be able to execute.

```sh
chmod+x 755 docker-healthcheck
```

After building the image again the healthcheck started working.